# MSBuild not finding the DLL

Tags: msbuild

I emit a console app with `Mono.Cecil` and I want to integrate MSBuild into the build process. But then when I run `dotnet build` on my custom project file, MSBuild throws an error saying `Expected file "obj\Debug\net5.0\refint\test.dll" does not exist`. It's trying to find the generated assembly inside the `refint` folder. When the assembly gets generated inside `obj\Debug\net5.0\test.dll` as it should. Is there a way I can change the path where MSBuild looks for the output assembly? Everything on the side of the IL generator works, I even get a runnable exe inside the `build` folder. Here's my project file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <DefaultLanguageSourceExtension>.ao</DefaultLanguageSourceExtension>
    <OutputPath>C:\Users\filip\source\alto\samples\test\obj\Debug\net5.0\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="CreateManifestResourceNames" />

  <Target Name="CoreCompile" DependsOnTargets="$(CoreCompileDependsOn)">
    <Exec Command="dotnet run --project &quot;$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\..\..\src\aoc\aoc.csproj&quot; -- @(Compile->'$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)', ' ') /o &quot;@(IntermediateAssembly)&quot; @(ReferencePath->' /r &quot;%(Identity)&quot;', ' ')"
          WorkingDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `IntermediateOutputPath` contains path to output folder, e.g. `obj\debug\net5.0\`. You should update this property

Comment: The `IntermediateOutputPath` is not the problem. It was set to the correct path. I figured out a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't read the whole error message.

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100-preview.7.21379.14\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4527,5): error : Expected file "obj\Debug\net5.0\refint\test.dll" does not exist.
```

It actually points me to a file where the error was thrown. This is where:

```xml
<!-- Copy the reference assembly build product (.dll or .exe). -->
    <CopyRefAssembly
        SourcePath="@(IntermediateRefAssembly)"
        DestinationPath="$(TargetRefPath)"
        Condition="'$(ProduceReferenceAssembly)' == 'true' and '$(CopyBuildOutputToOutputDirectory)' == 'true' and '$(SkipCopyBuildProduct)' != 'true'"
            >

      <Output TaskParameter="DestinationPath" ItemName="ReferenceAssembly"/>
      <Output TaskParameter="DestinationPath" ItemName="FileWrites"/>

    </CopyRefAssembly>
```

It's trying to make a reference assembly when I don't need one. So I just set the `ProduceReferenceAssembly` property to `false`, since I don't need one.